# Didn't have vs I had no

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

When to use I didn't have and I had no?

E.g.

> Sorry, I didn't have any option but to change this.
>
> Sorry, I had no option but to change this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special rule.  Generally speaking you could be positive/assertive about it (and use "*I **had no** something*") or negative (and use "*I **didn't have** something*"), the meaning is the same -- something was not in your possession.

Comment: Sorry to ping you here, but didn't know how to do it otherwise! You deleted your answer to the *noticed my swimming ...*  question. Erm, my comments under there were not meant to undermine your answer. Just a nudge to put more in! That was my upvote on your question!!!! Could you undelete your answer because it is useful for learners here!

Answer (score 1):

There's very little difference in meaning between these sentences, that is, no + noun shows greater negation than not any + noun.